# Accessing array list methods from another class

Tags: java, arraylist, tui

I have two classes I want to use together. An array list class and a Text User Interface class which will call methods from the array list class in order to complete tasks.

Whenever I try to call methods with parameters in my array list class from my TUI class, it gives me an error.

I'm trying to access an (add) method in my arrayList class from a TUI class, which will add a user to my arrayList. Can somebody please tell me how to fix this. The method that is returning the error is the 'public void addBorrower()' at the bottom of my TUI class.

My two classes are below in full.

This is my TUI class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BorrowerTUI
{

private BorrowerList borrowerList;
private Scanner myScanner;


public BorrowerTUI()
{
    myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    BorrowerList borrowerList = new BorrowerList();
}

public void menu()
{
int command = -1;
while (command != 0)
{   
    displayMenu();
    command = getCommand();
    execute (command);
}
}



private void displayMenu()
{
System.out.println( "Options are" );
System.out.println( "Enter 1" );
System.out.println( "Enter 2" );
System.out.println( "Enter 3" );
System.out.println( "Enter 4" );

}

private void execute( int command)
{
if ( command == 1)
    addBorrower();
else
if ( command == 2 )
    getNumberOfBorrowers();
else
if ( command == 3)
    quitCommand();
else
if ( command == 4)
    quitCommand();
else
if ( command == 5)
    quitCommand();
else
    System.out.println("Unknown Command");
}


private int getCommand()
{
    System.out.print ("Enter command: ");
    int command = myScanner.nextInt();
    myScanner.nextLine(); 
    return command;
}

public void getNumberOfBorrowers()
{
    int command = myScanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("We have" + borrowerList.getNumberOfBorrowers() + "borrowers");
}

public void quitCommand()
{
    int command = myScanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Application Closing");
    System.exit(0);
}


public void addBorrower()
{

    borrowerList.addBorrower(Borrower borrower);
}
}
```

This is my array list class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BorrowerList
{
   private ArrayList<Borrower> borrowers;    


   public BorrowerList()
   {
       borrowers = new ArrayList<Borrower>();
    }

   public void addBorrower(Borrower borrower)
   {
       borrowers.add(borrower);
   }

   public int getNumberOfBorrowers()
   {
       return borrowers.size();
   }

   public boolean getBorrower(String libraryNumber)
   {
       for(Borrower borrower : borrowers)

       borrower.getLibraryNumber();
       return true;
   }

   public void getBorrower(int borrowerEntry)
   {
       if (borrowerEntry < 0)
       {
           System.out.println("Negative entry: " + borrowerEntry);
       }
       else if (borrowerEntry < getNumberOfBorrowers())
       { 
           Borrower borrower = borrowers.get(borrowerEntry);
           borrower.printBorrowerDetails();
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("No such entry: " + borrowerEntry);
       }
   }

   public void getAllBorrowers()
   {
        for(Borrower borrower : borrowers)
        {
            borrower.printBorrowerDetails();
            System.out.println();
        }
   }

   public void removeBorrower(int borrowerEntry)
   {
        if(borrowerEntry < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Negative entry :" + borrowerEntry);
        }
        else if(borrowerEntry < getNumberOfBorrowers())
        {
            borrowers.remove(borrowerEntry);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No such entry :" + borrowerEntry);
        }
   }

   public boolean removeBorrower(String libraryNumber)
   {
        int index = 0;
        for (Borrower borrower: borrowers)
        {
            if (libraryNumber.equals(borrower.getLibraryNumber()))
            {
                borrowers.remove(index);
                return true;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return false;
   }


   public int search(String libraryNumber)
   {
       int index = 0;
       for (Borrower borrower : borrowers)
       {
           if (libraryNumber.equals(borrower.getLibraryNumber()))
           {
               return index;
           }
           else
           {
               index++;
           }
       }
       return -1;
   }    
}
```

Borrower Class:

```
public class Borrower
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String libraryNumber;
    private int noOfBooks;
    private Address address;


    public Borrower(String fName, String lName, String lNumber, 
                    String street, String town, String postcode)
    {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        libraryNumber = lNumber;
        noOfBooks = 1;        
        address = new Address(street, town, postcode);
    }


    public Borrower(String fName, String lName, String lNumber, int     numberOfBooks, 
                    String street, String town, String postcode)
    {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        libraryNumber = lNumber;
        noOfBooks = numberOfBooks;         
        address = new Address(street, town, postcode);
    }


    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }


    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }


    public String getLibraryNumber()
    {
        return libraryNumber;
    }


    public int getNoOfBooks()
    {
        return noOfBooks;
    }


    public void printBorrowerDetails()
    {
        System.out.println( firstName + " " + lastName 
                           + "\n" + address.getFullAddress()
                           + "\nLibrary Number: " + libraryNumber
                           + "\nNumber of loans: " + noOfBooks);
    }     




    public void borrowBook()
    {
        noOfBooks = noOfBooks + 1;
        System.out.println("Books on loan: " + noOfBooks);        
    }


    public void borrowBooks(int number)
    {
        noOfBooks = noOfBooks + number;
        System.out.println("Books on loan: " + noOfBooks);        
    }


    public void returnBook ()
    {
        noOfBooks = noOfBooks - 1 ;
        System.out.println("Books on loan: " + noOfBooks);        
        }


    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address.getFullAddress();
    }


    public void setAddress(String street, String town, String postcode)
    {
        address.setFullAddress(street, town, postcode);
    }


    public void printAddress()
    {
        address.printAddress();
    }

} // end class
```

Comment: try changing `borrowerList.addBorrower(Borrower borrower);` for `borrowerList.addBorrower(new Borrower());` on your `addBorrower` method.

Comment: Yeah, you forgot to give the `addBorrower(...)` method a Borrower parameter.

Comment: I've amended my code to that, but now I am getting an error 'No suitable constructor found for Borrower(no arguments)'